# I need all calculated solutions that get close or equal to a static value, with predetermined values from an array of numbers

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I need help with a problem and I'm struggling to figure out how to even start.

**PROBLEM**

I have a static value: `500000`. Call it `CAP`.

I have a second, random-ish, value: `497548`. Let's call it `CURRENT`. This value is usually between 1000 and 4000 below `CAP`.

I need to get `CURRENT` as close or equal to `CAP` with a combination of predetermined values, and I want to return every possible solution.

These values are as following:

```
const TURN_IN_VALUE = 398; 

// The following is important for the returned solutions
// array index = rank. Index starts at 1.
const KILL_VALUES = {
  60: [199, 210, 221, 233, 246, undefined, 274, 289, undefined, 321, 339, 358, 377],
  59: [178, 188],
  58: [159, undefined, 176],
  57: [141, 1148],
  56: [124, 131],
  55: [109, 115, 121],
  54: [95, 100],
  53: [82],
  52: [70],
  51: [59],
  50: [49],
  49: [40, 42],
  48: [32],
};
```

Values that are defined as `undefined` are unconfirmed and unsafe to use, so we skip them.

**RULES**

- Solution should be no more than 5 off from `CAP`
- Solution can not exceed `CAP`
- `KILL_VALUES` can be used 2 times
- `TURN_IN_VALUE` can be used 13 times
- You can only add, never subtract

The returned solution should be something like

```
solutions = [
  {
    capAt: 499997,
    kills: [{
      60: 377,
      rank: 13,
      amount: 1,
    }, {
      53: 82,
      rank: 1,
      amount: 1,
    }],
    turnins: 5,
   },
   ... // all other solutions
]
```

Comment: I assume you mean you can *and and subtract* those values. Are you familiar with the knapsack problem?

Comment: Hey! No, you can't subtract. Only add. The Knapsack Problem seems to be the perfect thing to look into, thanks for that!